# Trouble connecting to raspberry pi via command prompt

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I've entered

```
ssh pi@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

in my command terminal, but keep getting the error

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: connection refused.
```

I know my IP address is correct, and ssh is installed on my computer. I've accessed this same raspberry pi on this computer before, so I'm not sure what the problem is. When i try to run ssh localhost, I get the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: `connection refused` generally means `sshd` is not running on the raspberryPi -- or -- you moved `sshd` to a port other than `22` on the raspberryPi in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. On the raspberryPi, what does the output of `systemctl status sshd` show? If not running, then as root (or admin) `systemctl start sshd`.